# WinJS ListView Tap-and-Hold

Tags: windows-8, winjs

In the WinJS ListView Control, how do you handle a tap and hold gesture for an item?

Each item template has an item and the contextmenu handler works via mouse, but not touch for the tap and hold gesture:

```
 <div class="Item" oncontextmenu="itemContextMenu()">
 ...
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may possibly be done via attaching the MSGestureHold event to the div.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771894(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I've tried that by adding onmsgesturehold="itemContextMenu()" to the div but the event handler doesn't get called.

Comment: I'll try to throw a sample together later, but looking at the samples for it (I haven't tried it on an item template item though) theres multiple steps: 1. Create the MSGesture object and target it to your element. 2. Add the event listener for MSGestureHold to your div.  PS The sample above does work in Win8 - copy and replace the entire default.html in a new Winjs blank app and it should work and you should see the event. The only 'gotcha' here may be the list view already listening for that event to use it for the item select gesture.